# What raspberry pi browser is supported by selenium and supports html5 video?

Tags: raspbian

I have tried phantom js but the html5 video won't load, upon googling it seems as if it was never supported. I have tried geckodriver for firefox-esr 52.9 but the video also won't load. I tried chromediver but I could not get this to work for the life of me, I feel as though it could be my best option if anyone has any instructions on getting this working that would be great.

Also does firefox-esr 60 support html5 and how would I install this on my pi with geckodriver?

It does not matter if the video plays poorly/skips I just need the content to load. Anya dvice or suggestions would be very helpful, thanks!

Comment: Did you try Chromium? Chromium is a fully featured web browser, included with the Raspbian Stretch installation.